# Identify property of expectation

Tags: probability

I am unable to figure out which property of expectation is used in the following expression:

$E[(H^TH)^{-1}H^TWW^TH(H^TH)^{-1}]=E_{W}E_{H|W}[(H^TH)^{-1}H^TWW^TH(H^TH)^{-1}]$

$H,W$ are matrices of random variables. I found this in a book on statistical signal processing but cannot find anywhere how $E$ has been broken down into $E_{W}E_{H|W}$. Please help.

Comment: Maybe it is just the law of total expectation? Sorry I am not sure about those subscript notation anyway.

Comment: @BGM $E_H$ represents the expectation with respect to probability density function of H

Comment: Are you sure it's $E_{H/W}$ and not $E_{H|W}$? And are they really in this order? $E_WE_{H|W}$ would make more sense.

Comment: @joriki Yes you are right, it is $E_{H|W}$. This is from a book that is not printed yet. So it could be the case that the order is also reversed. Can you please explain how $E$ can be broken down into $E_{W}E_{H|W}$ .

Comment: Please correct the question. The question should stand for itself and not rely on the comments in order to be understandable. There's an edit link underneath the question.

Comment: @joriki I have corrected the question.